# Add search fields to search bar magento

Tags: php, forms, magento, search

A friend has asked me to look at a website they had built (long story short they fell out so site didnt get finished). There is a search bar on the left hand side with 3 different search categories

[image: Searchbox]

Ive found the code for it in form.mini.phtml

```
<div id="search1">
<h3>
SEARCH &gt;&gt;&gt;
</h3>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
<div id="label_area">
<div id="label_area">
</div>
<input type="text" name="label" id="label" value="Label &gt;&gt;&gt;" onclick="if(this.value!='Label &gt;&gt;&gt;'){ } else { this.value =''; } "size="15" class="text2">
</div>            
<div id="label_area">
<div id="label_area">
</div>
<input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" value="Artists &gt;&gt;&gt;" onclick="if(this.value!='Artists &gt;&gt;&gt;'){ } else { this.value =''; } "size="15" class="text2">  
</div>           
<div id="label_area">
<div id="label_area">
</div>
<input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="text2" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" /></div>
<div id="label_area"> <input type="image" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/go.jpg')?>" />

</div>

</form>
</div>
<!--<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
<div class="form-search">
    <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span>    </button>-->
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Keywords>>>>>>>') ?>');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
 <!--  </div>
</form>-->
```

It looks like the developer has hashed this together, My question is, how do go about getting the label/artist fields working? sorry for the clumsiness, Im a novice with PhP, Ive tried a couple of approaches with no joy, thank you very much in advance :)